# Couchdb on Android

Tags: android, couchdb, synchronization

I am trying to evaluate couchdb and its potential for solving the sync problem on Android but I can't find any documentation that answers my questions regarding how replication to Android devices works.

It looks like the focus todolist couchapp is intended to demonstrate what I am looking for.  Does it automatically sync todo's between webapp and device?

Also, how do I get the focus couchapp onto the Android device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Paul: regarding your last question

> Also, how do I get the focus couchapp
>   onto the Android device?"

It is mentioned in the video link posted above, but to shorten things for others searching the same matter:

I assume you know how `couchapp push` is working since you seem to be using the

"focus" [couchone/Focus@github](https://github.com/couchone/Focus) couchapp. Otherwise couchapp.org provide a a nice [tutorial](http://couchapp.org/page/couchapp-usage).

Pushing apps to Android couchdb can be done via port-forwarding with [the Android Debug Bridge](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html) , which is shipped with [the Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

On unix like systems the easiest way to use adb would be to open a terminal, "cd" to the sdk directory and to the included "tools/" directory. From there you could call

```
./adb forward tcp:5985 tcp:5984
```

Which will basically enable you to go to "localhost:5985" on your computer and will be redirected to the couchdb running on your android device.
Assuming that you have

1. installed CouchDB from the market and running
2. enabled debugging on your phone
3. have connected your phone:)

Answer (score 3):

You can watch Couchdb Android video. It might help
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3RdcKWYGqig