# Is it possible to use Couch DB or MySql or any other DB in Android?

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite, couchdb

We know that Android uses SQLite as its default database. My question is: Is it possible to replace this by CouchDB or MySql or any other database and successfully run it? Has anybody done this? I went through  [What are requirements to use CouchDB on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399070/what-are-requirements-to-use-couchdb-on-android),  and other questions in SO, but I'm not completely clear about it. It does seem possible to install [CouchDB on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995881/couchdb-on-android), but as an app. I want to know if it's possible to replace SQLite with Couch or MySql or any other DB.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can indeed use CouchDB on Android.

Here's a video discussing CouchDB http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3RdcKWYGqig

You will need an external SD card.  It runs as a service so you can have multiple apps using CouchDB.  It also has amazing replication capabilities.  So if you need to sync with a master database then COuchDB makes this very easy.

There is more information available in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4956789/808940

There are also some tutorials available on the web but to get started you can download the CouchDB app from Android Marketplace.

Comment: Thanks a million! I was looking forward for this answer. I went through the SO link you've provided but wasn't too sure of it. Do you know if the same is possible with MySql?

Comment: mySQL is the wrong approach.  You might be able to get a JDBC driver to connect to a remote instance but mySQL and Android are not likely bedfellows.  Android is not a scalable OS, mySQL requires far to many resources.  Stick with CouchDB ... you can even get support with http://www.couchbase.com

Answer (score 2):

db4o runs on android, although it's an OODB, not an RDBMS. I suspect some Java-only DBs would run; Derby didn't at one point, H2 has at least some early support.

Comment: My aim is to run databases that are highly scalable. Esp NoSQL. By saying Java-only DBs, do we mean something like JDBC? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Rahul No, it means a DB written in Java. Scaling a DB on an Android device makes no sense to me: it's an Android device. Performance is limited by any number of factors. What do you think you need to do?

Comment: Basically my employer needs to know if it's possible. They haven't made clear what's on their mind. I personally think doing this won't take us anywhere. But then, they just want to know if it's possible. We are basically trying to implement/run a survey app for one of our clients which can store a good number of pictures in the local DB and then push everything onto the server when connection is established.

Comment: @Rahul Don't store pictures in the DB, store filenames of pictures.

Comment: You mean something like File url/uri? Sorry Dave. I'm relatively new to Java and Android and not a fully fledged developer. Might need some more info/help. Thanks.

Comment: @Rahul No, I mean file name. You take a picture, it's a file. Save the filename. No need to save the binary data in the DB, AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no other database you can use in android.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not really good with coding but I'd like to ask/know if it's possible to mess with the Android source code and replace SQlite with another DB by any far chance?

Comment: nopes,  I dont think anything else can take place of database. however if it is few information then it can be replaced with SharredPreferenced.

Comment: Ok! Thanks for answering. I'm particularly looking for something like what I've mentioned, and something outside Shared Preferences.

Comment: If I don't receive any other answer/s, 'll definitely accept your answer. Request you to wait for sometime. No offense please. But +1 for answering though.