# Oracle database mobile server vs Couchdb

Tags: android, oracle, couchdb

Solely looking at it from a mobile database point of view which is going to synchronize with a remote server,assuming it doesn't really matter if it is relational db or NoSQL,

what would be the better option to go along with?

Client platform is android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My vote would be for CouchDB.. The reason being, as NoSQL, it has good number of advantages. More than anything, you can make the user's data available offline.

Just in case you want further info on usage of CouchDB, I would like to request/suggest you to go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623096/is-it-possible-to-use-couch-db-or-mysql-or-any-other-db-in-android), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995881/couchdb-on-android) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399070/what-are-requirements-to-use-couchdb-on-android).

Comment: Well, i think i've already gone through those things in my initial research. Ok assuming i'm going ahead with Couch, would you suggest using Mobile Couchbase or TouchDb? Also, have you developed using couchdb on mobile?

Comment: I was half way thru' my development using Mobile Couchbase when the project was abandoned due to few inexplicable reasons. I haven't worked on TouchDB, as a result of which, I can't really comment on that. AFAIK, Mobile Couchbase has more support. I think it could be safer if you stick to that, but then again, I can't fully vouch for it.

Answer (score 1):

I want to point out that Oracle Database Mobile Server also makes the data available offline, that's what it's designed to do. In addition to syncing your mobile database, it also offers device mgmt. For more info:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/database-mobile-server/overview/index.html

I've not used the Couchbase solution, but I do know some of the team over there, and they seem like very smart people.

What it comes down to: if you want/need an Oracle backend, then you should use Oracle Database Mobile Server. If you want to experiment with NoSQL, then Couchbase would be the way to go.

Eric Jensen, 
Oracle PM

Comment: Is there an android client library?
How much more efficient is synchronization than that off couchbase? The reason why i want to go with couch is to support rapid prototyping at the moment.

Comment: Yes, the Android platform is fully supported. We offer both the data sync and device mgmt. We have not done efficiency/performance comparisons vs couchbase. If you decide to investigate this yourself, I'd like to hear about the results.

Comment: Just a note that the Oracle Database Mobile Server costs about 16K.